# May I change the table of content if using Markdown in ReadTheDocs?

Tags: markdown, read-the-docs

I understand the Table Of Contents may be edited (i.e. sorting elements, using child nodes, etc) with [TOC directives](http://sphinx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/markup/toctree.html) when using [Sphinx](http://sphinx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

> Is this possible to achieve when using Markdown ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it requires a bit of modification, however, it should get the job done.

Check out https://github.com/rtfd/recommonmark for instructions.

To further elaborate you'll need to have pip install recommonmark via `pip install recommonmark`

Then, inside of your `conf.py` file you'll want to add in the following:

```
from recommonmark.parser import CommonMarkParser

source_parsers = {
    '.md': CommonMarkParser,
}

source_suffix = ['.rst', '.md']
```

Source & see it in action at: http://recommonmark.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks, I've revised my response. Appreciate the feedback. @Mogsdad

Comment: That's a nice answer now! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Ill check out and give feedback.